# add single quotes and commas outside the quotes in string

Tags: sql, r, regex, paste, soql

I'd like to take a list of

```
Ids <- c("00234nisduf", "928347ksjdfn", "92837sdfjkbnfgh")
Ids
[1] "00234nisduf"     "928347ksjdfn"    "92837sdfjkbnfgh"
```

And turn it into a SOQL query:

```
Id_Query <- "'00234nisduf', '928347ksjdfn', '92837sdfjkbnfgh'"
```

The output I'm looking for: `'00234nisduf', '928347ksjdfn', '92837sdfjkbnfgh'` must have single quotes around each Id and a comma after the quotes for each Id.

I've tried `paste(Ids, collapse = ",")` and trying to mix with `gsub("\\"" "'", Ids)` but no luck so far.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `gsub('\\"', "'", Ids)`?

Comment: doesn't do anything. Also, I need a comma after each Id. If that worked it would only replace the double quotes with single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that takes a string and a new string, applies sQuote to its second argument, and uses paste to combine the second argument with the first.  Call that function using

```
Reduce(your_function, Ids)
```

EDIT:

Or, in one line:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep=","), sQuote(Ids))
```